# Web App converted to Maven Build Issue

Tags: java, spring, maven

Hi I am fairly new to Maven and we have a spring 3.0.5 mvc project which I have converted to a maven build from eclipse ide and then added dependencies to Pom.xml.

When I change the values on Pom.xml it is re building it automatically and I am 
able to run the web app having completed the dependencies.

the issue is when I try to run as maven build (clean install)I am having issues

-cannot find symbol(incompatible types)

I am confused, when changing saving after changing the pom.xml eclipse ties to build the app in which I was able to run it.

but when I use maven its giving me this error ma

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you say you have added everything needed it sounds like you mistaken one or more dependencies..which causes the issue...Identify the class and the where the class should be part of ...

Comment: i will be posting an image of a snippet of the pom and code affected.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a Maven issue its a Java issue it's clearly stating that in the Impl file it's found an Object but it requires a List of EmployeeCopTrainingSkill change it accordingly and it should work fine..

Comment: thanks for the reply but this is a working application, this just happens when I build it with maven.

Comment: If that' the case, can you confirm if all the classes are generated properly you may have missed it in the pom ....if you can  share the pom.xml  you'll get a definitive answer.

Comment: tried but pom.xml is too large. ill try to find a way to upload it